# Bitmap background in Edit Control

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to use a bitmap as a background in a standard edit control. Handling WM_CTLCOLOREDIT only allows to set background *color* via SetBkColor.
Subclassing Edit control and handling WM_ERASEBKGND doesn't work because the background is drawn (probably) in WM_PAINT method.
Is there any way to use custom bitmap as a background without resorting to creating my own control?

Comment: Notice that `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` also lets you specify the background brush. Put your bitmap there.

Comment: Perhaps http://www.gidforums.com/t-9691.html will point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is not possible.  EDIT dates from the 1980s and breaks the rules, the kind of thing they had to do back then to make it run on a 386SUX.  It paints without using WM_PAINT.  Which entirely breaks your bitmap.

Comment: Returning pattern brush in WM_CTLCOLOREDIT worked! I also had to call SetBkMode(TRANSPARENT).It's not ideal for me, I wanted to draw a background manually in WM_ERASEBKGND, but WM_CTLCOLOREDIT way is goon enough too. Thanks!